# toggle classes for a child element

Tags: jquery, class, toggle

```
$('.toggle').addClass('change_button').removeClass('toggle');
$(this).removeClass('change_button').addClass('toggle');
```

i have provided the demo of complete code below in the first comment.
 i have 2 sets of buttons 
1st set  
1.Lite 
 2.Medium 
 3.Heavy

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cugdZ/29/)

2nd set 
 1.Yes 
 2.No 
 
 what i want is those sets must act as radio buttons like demo provided below in the first comment

instead of radio buttons i have here block buttons and when the button is selected i want to change bagraund color

Comment: Code : - http://jsfiddle.net/cugdZ/27/  Radio buttons : - http://jsfiddle.net/BUMUq/

Comment: instead adding comment update your question with links

Comment: thats the single question. i want my buttons to act as radio buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:-

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4t4kt/)**

```
  $('.change_button.toggle',$(this).closest('div')).removeClass('toggle');
  $(this).addClass('toggle');

 });
```

Explanation:-

```
$('.change_button.toggle',$(this).closest('div')).removeClass('toggle');
```

This statement selects the elements with .change_button and .toggle class which resides in the parent div of the clicked element and removes its `toggle` class.

```
$(this).addClass('toggle');
```

Adds the class the selected element.

Comment: NO i have the same problem when select Lite in 1st set and then Yes in 2nd set the selection of Lite in1st set is lost

Comment: Sure.. Adding it in the answer

Comment: can you give me a mail ID or any means to PM you if i have any doubts.